# I need to remove the white space space that coming at the bottom of my website when im using elementor custom footer

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I replaced the normal footer with a custom Elementor header and footer plugin's footer. when it's showing there is a white space below the footer. but I can't remove that with CSS because it's not on the body. Can anyone you please help?

I want to remove this space below the footer, I even tried margin-bottom :-100px. but not working.

[Please check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pkPA.png)

[Screenshot with selected Body in Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shXGZ.png)

Website link - https://rozyroti.com/demo/cheftech/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I used this and the white space is removed from below the footer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your  reply. i used this and it worked!